# Windows Service (in C#) that can call a Python script that runs infinitely?

Tags: c#, python, windows, multithreading, windows-services

From what I understand, when you run a Windows Service, it calls 'onStart()' and will say that the service is 'starting' in the task manager until the 'onStart()' method runs through completely, to which it then says "running". I would like to create a thread to start a Bluetooth Advertising Script (written in Python3) that will advertise continuously whenever it is not connected to a device. When I try to create a thread and run the script, the service usually just displays "starting' in the task manager and never actually says "running", because the thread that I call within 'onStart()' to initiate the script never finishes I guess. Is there a way to get the service to start, only starting the thread after it as finished executing the 'onStart()'?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace WindowsService1
{
//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Service1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    private Boolean _started;
    public event System.EventHandler serviceChanged;
    Service1 serv = new Service1();
    static ThreadStart start = new ThreadStart(Adv_Py_Script);
    Thread Adv_Py_ScriptThread = new Thread(start);
    //Start_Adv s = new Start_Adv();
    //Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(s.Adv_Py_Script));



    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        isStarted = true;



        Thread.Sleep(5000);

    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected virtual void onServiceChanged() { serviceChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Boolean isStarted
    {
        get { return _started; }
        set
            {
            _started = value;
            onServiceChanged();
            }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        isStarted = false;

        serv.killPyThread(Adv_Py_ScriptThread);
        base.OnStop();
        // wait for threads to stop
        Adv_Py_ScriptThread.Join(60);

        try
        {
            string error = "";
           // Messaging.SMS.SendSMSTextAsync("5555555555", "Messaging Service stopped on " + System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), ref error);
        }
        catch
        {
            // yes eat exception if text failed
        }

}

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
    public void killPyThread(Thread thread)
    {
        thread.Interrupt();
        thread.Abort();
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

    private static void Adv_Py_Script()
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\bakere1\A19149\Projects\BLE_Advertiser.py";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python36_64\python.exe", fileName)
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While there might be other problems, the first one is that the Local Service account that your service (probably) runs as doesn't have permissions to the location `C:\Users\bakere1\A19149\Projects\`

If you change the "Run As" account to something with permissions, you'll get farther. I'm not a big python geek, but if your py app requires any sort of user I/O it will fail, since there is no console session assigned to it.

Also, if you have roaming profiles, the service gets started at before the user folder is available, so it will hang or fail.

Comment: Thanks - Do you know how I would change the permissions to allow it access?

Comment: In the Windows Services Control Panel, change the "Run As" account to something that has the permissions your app needs.

Comment: I gave myself administrator access in that section, but still get the '1053' error, which says it timed out when trying to start the service

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to wait for someone who knows more Python than me. I've never tried to glue Python into a windows service.